# Embedded Spotify playlist looks like it was meant for desktop when I open my site on my mobile device

Tags: html, mobile, responsive-design

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want my website to look more legible on mobile, currently it looks like it’s meant for desktop.

I tried adding a width of 50% to everything which did make the content look bigger but I had to zoom in to make everything fit the screen which doesn’t look viable

Anyways, I know nothing about coding, I did thin with the help of chatgpt and I believe it’s written in html

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow !  I would suggest that you learn about responsive-design and come back if you sun into issues. Also, share the portion of your code that you need hep with.